# How to understand the memory protection scheme of IBM/370?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I was confused when I met a problem while reading "Operating System Concepts"(7th edition) which is :

In the IBM/370, memory protection is provided through the use of keys. A key is a 4-bit quantity. Each 2K block of memory has a key (the storage key) associated with it. The CPU also has a key (the protection key) associated with it. A store operation is allowed only if both keys are equal, or if either is zero. Which of the following memory-management schemes could be used successfully with this hardware?

a. Bare machine

b. Single-user system

c. Multiprogramming with a fixed number of processes

d. Multiprogramming with a variable number of processes

e. Paging

f. Segmentation

I have some problems about that: **How were such keys calculated? Why it provided another way of  "either is zero" while the first way was already seemingly secure?(I mean what is "either is zero" used for and under what circumstance "either is zero" is efficient instead of matching two keys to see if they are the same.)**

Comment: The kernel calculated such keys

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have some other problems: What if two blocks have same keys? What should we pay attention to while using such hardware?

Comment: Basically, the system is limited to 15 simultaneous "user" processes, though the kernel can of course "swap" keys (at moderate expense) to enable more in a sort of time-slicing (and I would imagine that the system may have reserved a key value for "hiding" pages from all processes).  Paging or segmentation is essentially unrelated to the storage key scheme.

Comment: Allowing a process with a zero key to access anywhere allows the kernel/operating system to access all of RAM.  Allowing a page with zero key to be accessed from any process enables "shared" memory, though I don't know how practical this is without a separate write-protect flag (which may or may not have been there), and the "feature" may have just been an artifact of the zero process key scheme.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Disclaimer: this is not an informed answer, just an opinion</sub>

The "*either is zero*" seems to enable scenarios

1. CPU currently holds the zero protection key so it runs without restrictions in the god/root/kernel mode
2. memory block guarded by the zero key means that anyone can access it without any bureaucracy, it's covered by "public domain license"

Answer for "*how were such keys calculated*" by the Operating System would require some archaeology work. Starting point:

> [IBM Systems Reference Library, IBM System/360 Principles of Operation](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/ibm/360/princOps/A22-6821-7_360PrincOpsDec67.pdf)
>
> Page 17
>
> **System Structure → Protection Features**
>
> ...When the store-protection feature is installed, attempts to modify storage are monitored...
>   Two instructions - `SET STORAGE KEY` and `INSERT STORAGE KEY` - are provided for assigning and inspecting the code in a key. The same code may be used in many keys.
>
> A user's right of access to storage is identified by a four-bit *protection* key. For references caused by the CPU, the protection key in the current PSW is used; access by channels are controlled by the protection key assigned to the associated I/O operation...

See also:

- [Wikipedia: IBM System/360](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360)
- [Wikipedia: IBM System/370](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/370)